# Regex to match BIN ranges

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that matches the numbers `456725` to `456744` (Last 2 digits, 25-44), but can't seem to figure out a correct regex format. I've tried `^(4567[2-4][0-9])` but using this also matches `456745` which it shouldn't.

Comment: May I ask: *why*?

Comment: `[0-9]` is allowing 0 through 9 which `5` falls into you need to be more explicit for the 40s and 20s. `2[5-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-4]`.

Comment: Alright, chris85 is right. Still, do not forget about boundaries/anchors - `@"\\b4567(?:2[5-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-4])\\b"` or `@"^4567(?:2[5-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-4])$"`.

Comment: Thanks all! u guys ROCK!

Comment: @DonaldKing Can you please accept an answer so the question is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it like `^(4567[2-4][0-9])`, you are allowing any number in the range between `[2-4]` together with any number in the range between `[0-9]`, which is obviously not what you wanted.

So you need to change for something like:
`^4567(?:2[5-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-4])`

---

### **Explanation**

`^` asserts position at start of the string

`4567` matches the characters 4567 literally

**Non-capturing group** `(?:2[5-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-4])`

**1st Alternative** `2[5-9]`

`2` matches the character 2 literally

Match a single character present in the list `[5-9]`

**2nd Alternative** `3[0-9]`

`3` matches the character 3 literally

Match a single character present in the list `[0-9]`

**3rd Alternative** `4[0-4]`

`4` matches the character 4 literally

Match a single character present in the list `[0-4]`

---

You could use the page [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to learn more and read good explanations on the subject. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is just an integer it is best to just compare it as such...

For the regex though..the `^(4567` is correct your issue is the `[2-4]` and `[0-9]` those are independent of each other. You need to put the pieces together so only `25-29` and `40-44` are allowed.

This should get you on the right track:

```
^(4567(?:2[5-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-4]))$
```